# Connecting a +12V DC wire to a Voltage Regulator with 4 pinouts

Tags: voltage-regulator, dc

The voltage regulator I'm using has 4 pins (2 in, 2 out) pictured below.

The reason I purchased this regulator is that I want to convert +12V DC in to +5V DC current for connecting a Sony Projector to a compatible 3D transmitter. From a [post on avsforum](http://www.avsforum.com/forum/68-digital-projectors-under-3-000-usd-msrp/1524377-sony-vpl-hw40es-new-sony-sxrd-1080p-home-theater-projector-8.html#post24780721) I can conclude that pins 1 and 2 from the sony transmit +12V DC. They will be soldered together, and connected to the "+" 12V Input section of the voltage regulator. However, what do I do with the "-" port of the input?

Also on the 3d transmitter end, it expects a +5V DC, which I presume I should connect to he "+" section on the output label of the regulator, but what happens to the "-" side here?

**Fig1. SINOLLC DC 12V 24V to 5V 3A Converter Step Down Regulator 5V Regulated Power Supplies Transformer Converter**

[image: Voltage regulator]

**Fig2. Pin description of the VESA 3d Transmitter (note pin "A", which is +5V)**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "+" connections connect to the positive rail of each respective power connection, and the "-" connects to the corresponding ground rail. So the positive connection of the 12V supply connects to the + input and its ground to the - input, and the + output supplies 5V and the - output its corresponding ground.

There is no need to connect the two grounds together unless you need to transmit signals between the 12V side and the 5V side.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think this pretty much answers my question.